# Android Facebook SDK 4 ShareLinkContent fails

Tags: android, share, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use the code below to allow app users to share my app via Facebook.

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(myUrlStr))             
                                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse("myImageUrlStr))
                                .setContentTitle(myContentTitleStr)                              
                                .setContentDescription(descriptionStr)
                                .build();

if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class) == true)
    shareDialog.show(content);
```

This code will invoke the Facebook Messenger, and let users select how to share my app. The code was perfectly working, but now for some reason it stopped! Now if try to share my app, I get the following message and the post fails:

> We're sorry this post is no longer available, it may have been removed.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176382/android-facebook-sdk-action-setplace-error-in-custom-stories-in-andoridfeed-d) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602381/sharing-to-facebook-shows-error-we-are-sorry-this-post-is-no-longer-available) posts, but they do not apply to my case, since, as mentioned, posting was perfectly working and without any reason it stopped one day.

Do you know if something has changed on the required permissions from Facebook? This is really weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is weird, but after removing this line from my Manifest file, it works again:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/app_name"/>
```

Found it from [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=91426) site.

Comment: it is about integer max limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check "app_name" in strings.xml and on FB developer page app name. It could be the same!